# Linux, C, ncurses: seg fault caused by printw

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, ncurses

Is there any reason why `printw()` would cause a segmentation fault?

Code is fine without it; broken with it.  It doesn't seem to be doing anything esoteric, so I'm not sure how to even begin to understand what is wrong here.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
#include <ncurses.h>
...
initscr();
noecho();
cbreak();
...
    void draw_court()
    {
        move(TOP_ROW-1, LEFT_COL+4);
        printw("LIVES REMAINING: 3");

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < RIGHT_COL; i++)
            mvaddch(TOP_ROW, LEFT_COL+i, H_LINE);

        for (i = 1; i < BOT_ROW-TOP_ROW; i++)
            mvaddch(TOP_ROW+i, LEFT_COL, V_LINE);

        for (i = 0; i < RIGHT_COL; i++)
            mvaddch(BOT_ROW, LEFT_COL+i, H_LINE);
    }
```

ETA: The stacktrace from gdb:

```
#0 0xb778a139 in _nc_printf_string () from /lib/libncurses.so.5
#1 0xb7785e04 in vwprintw () from /lib/libncurses.so.5
#2 0xb7785f63 in printw () from /lib/libncruses.so.5
#3 0x08048f23 in draw_court ()
#4 0x080489f4 in set_up ()
#5 0x0804890a in main ()
```

Comment: Is `TOP_ROW-1` the right calculation, or should it be `TOP_ROW+1`?  I'm thinking out-of-bounds error.

Comment: `TOP_ROW` is actually defined to be 5 - sorry, I know that's a little confusing.

Comment: I'd try running your program under valgrind to check for memory errors.

Comment: Should `i < RIGHT_COL` be `i < RIGHT_COL - LEFT_COL` ?  Or do you define `RIGHT_COL` as absolute, while `BOT_ROW` is relative?

Comment: Can you post the complete code? Cos sometimes, prints would be hiding the problem which is somewhere else

Comment: Just a silly guess, but have you tried `printw("%s", "LIVES REMAINING: 3");`

Comment: Also, `draw_box ()` is missing from the stack trace.  Is that expected or a sign of stack corruption?

Comment: @AdamLiss, this code actually only draws three borders of the box, but those lines are not causing me any trouble.  `printw()` will still segfault even when I have those commented out; the code runs fine if and only if the line with `printw()` is commented out.  (`BOT_ROW` is relative, it's determined from `ioctl()`.

Comment: Sorry, I've elided my code a little.  "draw_court" is actually "draw_box".  Editing again.

Comment: @AdamLiss, `printw("%s", "blah");` didn't work, but thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Are you running on a Mac?  This appears to be a known problem: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2010-03/msg00000.html

Comment: Okay, I solved it.  I missed that I was calling my method before `initscr()` because it doesn't choke on `mvaddch()`, so I was focusing on `printw()` as the source of the problem.  Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Ah, that bug report is good to know about, thanks!.  Actually I am running the code on a Linux server via SecureCRT from a Windows 7 machine, but I just bought an iMac and will soon be seeing life from the other side of the fence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you forget to call [initscr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/initscr.html)()?

Comment: `initscr()` is called elsewhere.  The code runs if I comment out the line with `printw()`.

Comment: I've edited it to show the initialization calls it makes before calling this method.

Comment: Crediting this as the solution, because the problem turned out to be that I was calling draw_court() before initscr().  I didn't think this was an issue because it works fine without that one line of code.  Strange that mvaddch will work before initscr() but not printw().

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is probably to run the code under `gdb` or another debugger, so you can see exactly what it's doing.

If that's not an option, check your indices for off-by-one errors, and then try commenting out portions of the (entire) program until you've arrived at the smallest snippet that still crashes; then post that if you'd like help debugging.

Also, because I can't help myself, you need only 2 loops to draw a box.  :-)

```
void draw_box()
{
    move(TOP_ROW-1, LEFT_COL+4);
    printw("LIVES REMAINING: 3");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < RIGHT_COL; i++) {  // should the limit be RIGHT_COL - LEFT_COL ?
        mvaddch(TOP_ROW, LEFT_COL+i, H_LINE);
        mvaddch(BOT_ROW, LEFT_COL+i, H_LINE);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < BOT_ROW-TOP_ROW; i++) {
        mvaddch(TOP_ROW+i, LEFT_COL, V_LINE);
        mvaddch(TOP_ROW+i, RIGHT_COL, V_LINE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the two loops.  :)  I'm going to edit my post with the stacktrace from gdb.